# How do I scrape different HTML files using RVEST and store it into an excel filesheet?

Tags: html, r, excel, web-scraping, rvest

I am not fluent in R and trying to piece together a solution for my issue. I have around 800 html files and I want to access each and every  element inside each of these files.

I have figured out how to individually do this with the website url

```
library(rvest)

scraping_wiki <- read_html("example.com")

scraping_wiki %>%
        html_nodes("h2")
```

and the output prints to my terminal. BTW, I am using the terminal R environment because I have no idea how to run an R program. I would like to know if there are any functions that will allow me to open multiple .html files, go through each of the H2 tags, and then put them into an excel file? Preferably one col for html file another col for all the H2 data? I'm extremely new to R and cannot wrap my head around some of the functions as it is not familiar. Any help is great : )

Comment: It would be easier to help if you add 2-3 links of your html files and show the expected output for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be helpful if you post some actual code to show what you actually want to do.  Here is a simple, and generic, example of how to do this.

```
library(rvest) #v.0.2.0.9000
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics" 
tb <- read_html(url) %>% html_node("table.wikitable:nth-child(2)") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)


library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(tb, "C:/mydata.xlsx")
```